# Java - Trimming trailing whitespace from a byte array

Tags: java

I have byte arrays similar to this:

```
[77, 83, 65, 80, 79, 67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32]
```

roughly equal to

```
[M , S, A, P, O, C,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ] when printed as chars.
```

Now I want to trim the trailing whitespace so it looks like:

```
[77, 83, 65, 80, 79, 67]
```

Easiest way to do this?

**Edit**: I don't want to deal with Strings because there is the possibility for non-printable bytes, and I can not afford to lose that data. It needs to be byte arrays :( Whenever I do convert to Strings, bytes like 01 (SOH) 02 (STX) etc are lost.

**Edit 2**: **Just to clarify. DO I lose data if I convert byte arrays to Strings? Now a little confused. What about if the bytes are of a different character set?**

Comment: Why aren't you working with strings?

Comment: Is it important to trim only the trailing whitespace, or can leading whitespace be trimmed as well? The different answers handle that in different ways.

Comment: I can't fathom a problem whereby you have a bunch of bytes and need to keep 0x01 and 0x02 bytes but discard trailing spaces. Further, Strings **can and do** contain those 0x01 and 0x02 bytes (converted to characters, of course); it's just that such characters are not printable. Keeping a byte array will not change the fact that the characters corresponding to those bytes are not printable.

Comment: I assumed they were not included at all. The situation has to do with legacy code that is incredibly finicky (long story).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without converting to a string:

```
byte[] input = /* whatever */;
int i = input.length;
while (i-- > 0 && input[i] == 32) {}

byte[] output = new byte[i+1];
System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, i+1);
```

---

#### Tests:

- [`[77, 83, 65, 80, 79, 67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32]` 
  → `[77, 83, 65, 80, 79, 67]`](http://ideone.com/usqeM)
- [`[77, 83, 65, 80, 79, 67]` → `[77, 83, 65, 80, 79, 67]`](http://ideone.com/HEZqg)
- [`[32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32]` → `[]`](http://ideone.com/aMXnr)
- [`[]` → `[]`](http://ideone.com/ugEmI)
- [`[77, 83, 65, 80, 79, 67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 80]`

  → `[77, 83, 65, 80, 79, 67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 80]`](http://ideone.com/KPFtM)

Comment: This is just the basic idea, not actually tested (I am on mobile currently). Probably contains an off-by-one error.

Comment: Awesome. This is similar to what I had already (except I didn't think to iterate backwards (and thus had complicated next byte checking).

Comment: but whitespace is not only 32 (space)

Comment: @MattBall Did you mean `i >= 0` instead of `i <= 0`?

Comment: You didn't have to create empty body for while, you can use `;` instead.

Comment: @ctomek you are technically correct. However, I follow (most of) Google's Java Style Guide, which dictates that [braces are always used where optional.](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1.1-braces-always-used)

Comment: @MattBall Ok, thanks for that info. I am using braces when there is only one statement, but when there are no statemens I prefer to use no braces. I am curious why did you choose to follow that convension?

Comment: @ctomek my own personal experiences. It's just easier to maintain/read/change over months/years _correctly._ For example: I once spent frustrating hours spent hunting down a bug due to an `if(...); {}` that shouldn't have had that little `;`. Once you follow a strict, consistent style, you can use tools like checkstyle to enforce it and detect bugs before the code is even executed.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way?  No guarantees on efficiency or performance, but it seems pretty easy.

```
byte[] results = new String(yourBytes).trim().getBytes();
```

Comment: Actually, trim will remove also leading spaces

Comment: That would trim both ends. I need trailing, and as per edited post, I need to do it without converting to String.

Comment: You don't lose bytes corresponding to non-printable characters when you convert to a String. A String is a sequence of characters, and non-printable characters are still characters.

Answer (score 0):

- change bytes to string
- call `text = text.replaceAll("\\s+$", ""); // remove only the trailing white space`
- change string to bytes

Comment: I know :) but notice, he want trailing spaces - trim() is bad

Answer (score 0):

Modification String `trim()` for `byte[]`. It cuts not only a tail of array but head too.

```
public byte[] trimArray(byte[] source) {
    int len = source.length;
    int st = 0;
    byte[] val = source;

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= SPACE)) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= SPACE)) {
        len--;
    }
    byte[] result;
    if ((st > 0) || (len < source.length)) {
        result = new byte[len - st];
        System.arraycopy(source, st, result, 0, result.length);
    } else {
        result = source;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Kotlin version of @matt-ball answer..

```
    private val zero = 0.toByte()
    private fun trim(src: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        var i = src.size
        while (i-- > 0 && src[i] == zero) {
        }

        val dst = ByteArray(i + 1)
        System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 0, i + 1)
        return dst
    }
```

How to use
val arrTrimmed =

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = new String(arrayWithWhitespace);
s = s.trim();
byte[] arrayWithoutWhitespace = s.getBytes();
```